# Format string with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to format a string that looks like this

```
BPT4SH9R0XJ6
```

Into something that looks like this

```
BPT4-SH9R-0XJ6
```

The string will always be a mix of 12 letters and numbers

Any advice will be highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a regex?

Comment: Not really, just figured that is whats most usually recommended

Comment: Will it always be same, i mean, add a `dash(-)` after every 4 characters?

Comment: Is the colouring on the '0Xj6' significant?

Comment: @Olly: It's because hexadecimal literals start with 0x.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try `Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})", @"$1-$2-$3");`

Regex is often derided, but is a pretty neat way of doing what you need.  Can be extended to more complex requirements that are difficult to meet using string methods.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, I know this can be done with substr etc but string concatenation often gets complex and is not very fun to write either :)

Comment: is there a way to say $1.toLower() or similar?

Comment: @Zanidd Yes, there's an [overload of Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) that allows you to use a custom function to generate the replacement string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `"(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})"` as your expression and `"$1-$2-$3"` as your replacement. This is, however, hardly a good use for regexp: you can do it much easier with [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

```
var res = s.Substring(0,4)+"-"+s.Substring(4,4)+"-"+s.Substring(8);
```

Answer (score 4):

If the rule is to always split in three block of four characters no need for a reg exp:

```
str.Substring(0,4) + "-" + str.Substring(4,4) + "-" + str.Substring(8,4)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that a combination of `String.Concat` and `string.Substring` should take care of everything that you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var str = "BPT4SH9R0XJ6";
  var newStr = str.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + str.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + str.Substring(8, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you want to do a regex?  you could just insert hyphens:

```
string s = "BPT4SH9R0XJ6";
for(int i = 4; i < s.length; i = i+5)
    s = s.Insert(i, "-");
```

This would keep adding hyphens every 4 characters, would not error out if string was too short/long/etc.

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct? You are not using the i variable. Also it's not very efficient since it creates new string object in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
return original_string.SubString(0,4)+"-"+original_string.SubString(4,4)+"-"+original_string.SubString(8,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = @"BPT4SH9R0XJ6";
string formattedString = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", str.Substring(0, 4), str.Substring(4,4), str.Substring(8,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with any length of string:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.Floor((myString.Length - 1) / 4d); i++)
            {
                myString = myString.Insert((i + 1) * 4 + i, "-");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended upp using this

```
var original = "BPT4SH9R0XJ6".ToCharArray();

var first = new string(original, 0, 4);
var second = new string(original, 4, 4);
var third = new string(original, 8, 4);
var mystring = string.Concat(first, "-", second, "-", third);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed the text you're operating on is the 12 character code then why don't you just use substring? Why do you need the Regex?

```
String theString = "AB12CD34EF56";
String theNewString = theString.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + theString.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + theString.Substring(8, 4);'
```